# How to copy the content inside index after modification to another in Elasticsearch using python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I need to copy of content inside `my_index` into another index after some modification. how to do that

Below is sample data and code to put inot the index.

```
test = [{'id':1,'name': 'A', 'subject': ['Maths', 'Accounting'],
        'type':'Contract', 'Location':'NY'},
    { 'id':2,  'name': 'AB', 'subject': ['Physics', 'Engineering'],
    'type':'Permanent','Location':'NY'},
    {'id':3,   'name': 'ABC',   'subject': ['Maths', 'Engineering'],
    'type':'Permanent','Location':'NY'}]

from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()
es.indices.create(index='myindex', ignore=400)
for e in test:
        es.index(index="myindex", body=e, id=e['id'])
```

From `myindex` I need extract `id` and `name` and copy into another index `my_index_1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If number of documents in "myindex" is not so high, you can use search API to get all data and extract what data you want and index them. For this purpose you can use a code like this:

```
res = es.search(index="myindex", body={"query":{"match_all":{}}})
for item in res.get("hits").get("hits"):
    es.index(index="my_index_1", body={"id":item.get("_id"), "name": item.get("_source").get("name")})
```

if the number of your data is higher (usually less than 10000) you can use upper code but it would be better to use limit and offset such below:

```
limit = 30
total_count = es.count(index="my_index", body={"query":{"match_all":{}}}).get("count")
offset = 0
while offset < total_count:
    res = es.search(index="myindex", body={"query":{"match_all":{}}}, size=limit, from_=offset)
    offset+=limit
    for item in res.get("hits").get("hits"):
        es.index(index="my_index_1", body={"id":item.get("_id"), "name": item.get("_source").get("name")})
```

if your data is large in number you need to use scroll api to get all documents:

```
es = es.search(index="myindex",body={"query":{"match_all":{}}},scroll="1m")
scroll_id = res.get("_scroll_id")
items = es.get("hits").get("hits")
while len(items):
    for item in items:
        es.index(index="my_index_1", body={"id":item.get("_id"), "name": item.get("_source").get("name")})
    query = {
             "scroll": "1m",
             "scroll_id": scroll_id
          }
    res =es.scroll(scroll_id=scroll_id, body=query)
    items = res.get("hits").get("hits")
```